# cPanel automatically do "yum update"

Tags: yum, cpanel

cPanel with its update cron does automatically "yum update" and it updated the kernel etc.

So, can I know somehow when he updates it, so I can reboot my server, I do not want to check it manually everyday. I have too much servers, or I need to reboot it regular once at month?

Any solution?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

Update the cron job to mail you when stuff gets upgraded.
You are probably better off grepping through the output for things that require a reboot (like the kernel), otherwise you're pretty much guaranteed an email every day: Linux distributions are constantly pushing new software into production.

---

#### A few general notes

1. **cPanel is not a person, nor does it have a gender.**
   The proper pronoun for referring to cPanel is "it", though the noun-phrase "that worthless piece of software getting in my way" is often used by professional system administrators.
2. **You should be paying closer attention to what cPanel does during its automatic upgrades.**
   If cPanel has a cron job that's just installing updates without asking you, how can you maintain control of your environment?
   As a system administrator you really need to look at what is being upgraded, or one day you'll upgrade something that breaks your environment and you'll have a heck of a time tracking down what happened.  You should be generally aware of what version of every major component is running on your system...
3. **You should be performing regular server reboots as part of preventative maintenance.**
   This is the only way to ensure that when you have to reboot your server for unexpected reasons (bad RAM, idiot tripping over the power cord, etc.) it will come back up in a consistent state and behave as expected.

Comment: This notices make me really laugh.
Of course I get mail when cron is executed lol
But that is done every day at 04:00 AM!
I used HE because my mother language is not ENGLISH, so I am not Linux dumb etc.

Comment: #1 was intended in jest (more as a way to badmouth cPanel).  And there's no requirement that you act on the email the second you receive it - you can read it the next morning and decide if it requires action. (You should however ensure that you only receive an email if it *does* require action, else you will become accustomed to ignoring them as noise)

Comment: @voretaq7 Yes, there is a cron to "update" nightly. Like when it randomly moves Perl just because cPanel felt like it.... That was really fun.